# How to add element in element using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have some code like this:

```
<p>Nuno</p>
<p>Eimes</p>
```

How can I manipulate it like this:

```
<p><a href="name/Nuno">Nuno</a></p>
<p><a href="name/Eimes">Eimes</a></p>
```

I've tried:

```
var name=$(this).text();
$( "p" ).each(function() {
  $(this).prepend('<a href="id/'+ $(this).text() +'"> ');
$(this).append("</a>");
});
```

but it results:

```
<p><a href="id/Nuno"> </a>Nuno</p>
<p><a href="id/Eimes"> </a>Eimes</p>
```

the `<a>` is not inside `$('p').text();` also if i change to `name`. it didn't show the value.

Comment: What's `this` in `var name=$(this).text();`? What's the scope?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple and [.wrapInner()](http://api.jquery.com/wrapInner/)

```
$('p').wrapInner(function(){
    return '<a href="name/' + $(this).text() + '" />' // even this.innerHTML instead of $(this).text() will do
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3hXTv/)

Answer (score 2):

```
$( "p" ).each(function() {
   var text = $(this).text();
   $(this).wrapInner('<a href="name/'+text+'"></a>');
 });
```

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tJWYH/2/)

Comment: @MattBall what do you mean..?

Comment: @DipeshParmar nobody knows you are going to edit it... so when a person sees an answer they judge by what they see at that time...

Answer (score 0):

Once you've extracted the name, I would just rewrite the whole code within the `<p></p>` tags again:

```
var name=$(this).text();
$( "p" ).each(function() {
  $(this).html('<a href="name/'+ $(this).text() +'">' + $(this).text() + '</a>');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to grab the inner stuff, then replace everything in the tag with the new HTML:

```
var name=$(this).text();
$( "p" ).each(function() {
    old = $(this).html();
    $(this).html('<a href="id/'+ old +'">'+old+'</a>');
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SpaceDog/dn6xr/)

Answer (score 0):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kfHsR/)

```
$('p').html(function () {
    return '<a href="name/' + this.innerHTML + '">' + this.innerHTML + '</a>';
});
```

[.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/)